# How to detect when a Kubernetes liveness / readiness probe fails and invoke an endpoint passing some information about the pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have set up liveness and readiness probes for an application, e.g.:

```
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /actuator/health/readiness
        port: 8080
    ...
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /actuator/health/liveness
        port: 8080
```

What I would like to do is whenever the probe is invoked by Kubernetes, its result is sent to an endpoint passing some additional information suchs as pod name, Docker image used, value from a secret, etc.

```
PROBE INVOKED -> RESULT COLLECTED -> INVOKE ENDPOINT (http://xxx - payload {"probe": "liveness", "result": "OK", "image" : "app:1.0.0", "key" : "VALUE_EXTRACTED_FROM_A_SECRET", ...}
```

Could you indicate a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this (e.g. depending on your pipeline).
You could call the probe endpoints yourself and react if the pod is not in the desired state.
You could could then call `kubectl describe`, `log` etc. and pass the result to your endpoint.
You could do so in with different approaches bash, python, etc...

Comment: My main doubt here is how and where place the automation that detects the probe invocation. Ideally if Kubernetes readinessProbe/livenessProbe yaml had some kind of hook I could run whatever I wanted (bash, python) there as you suggest. However as it doesn't exist, I would need to use something that periodically asks for that info. Any recommendation for this?

Comment: You could use your pipeline: Have a deploy step and have a integration test step afterwards. That is how we do it.

Comment: That would give deployment feedback in the pipeline, however I'd like to detect failure during the application lifetime.

Comment: Well then you have another huge set of possibilities to do so. But in the end it comes down to something like a service or a function (as in AWS lambda or Googles Functions) which does the job for you pinging a health endpoint and reacting accordingly.